# How to programmatically remove a npm package?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, node-modules, npm-install

I want to be able to dynamically add and remove npm packages at runtime in a node.js application. Installing a package using `npm.install(...)` works fine, but `npm.remove(...)` is only removing the package from the filesystem but the actual module is still requirable in the code. I tried clearing the npm cache and various modules like `decache` but not luck. How do I programmatically remove the package?

This code belows illustrates my process using the package 'commander' as an example.

```js
 const npm = require("npm");
 const assert = require("assert");

 const name = "commander";

 npm.load({}, error => {

   try{
     console.log(require(name));

   } catch(e){
     console.log("not available - good");
   }
    //install the package
    npm.install(name,  (error, data) => {

      console.log("error install",error);
      assert(require(name) != null)  

      //remove the package
      npm.remove(name,  (error, data) => {  

        console.log("error remove",error);
        require.cache = {};

        //still here, even so the files have been removed from the FS
        console.log(require(name));
      })

    });    


 });
```

Comment: Instead of `require.cache = {}` try `delete require.cache[name]`. Also try `console.log(require.cache)` before `console.log(require(name));` to make sure it was removed from cache.

Comment: Tried that, actually the keys for require.cache appear to be the absolute path of the main file of the package. This here does what you propose ```delete require.cache[require.resolve(name)]```, when I do that I get the error ```Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/usr/local/.../node_modules/commander/index.js'```when I require the module